# PlaceAutocomplete с gps кнопкой

Tags: java, android, gps, autocomplete

*Я установил себе в приложение* `PlaceAutocomplete` *и получаю с него* `latitude` *и* `longitude`. *Все работает отлично.*

Пример скрина как я хочу добавить кнопку для автоопределения местоположения.
[image: поиск с gps кнопкой]

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST);
```

Теперь я хотел бы добавить кнопку, которая автоматически определяла местоположение, как это сделать?

Comment: а разве на картинке не она указана? справа по центру

Comment: @iFr0z то что на скрине это пример, а которая на гитхабе проект с этого скрина она же просто поисковик, мне именно гугловый нужно чтобы получать данные lat и lon

Comment: Я просто не понимаю для чего в вопросе `PlaceAutocomplete`, если Вам нужен совсем другой функционал, и вот как раз по нему то ничего не указано. В чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @iFr0z в вопросе он так как я на данный момент нашел только метод через него получать список городов при вводе и потом парсить координаты с нее, если же есть другой метод то я буду рад